# changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity angular2

Tags: angular, ngsanitize

I am trying to load a pdf document in an  tag in angular2 Dynamically, and when I am trying to change the URL iths throwing an error saying

> SafeResourceUrlImplchangingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity:
>   "localhost:8002/pdf.pdf"**proto**: 
>   SafeValueImplconstructor:
>   SafeResourceUrlImpl()getTypeName: ()**proto**: Object
>
> localhost:8002/pdf.pdf Failed to load resource:
>   net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Here's how I am setting the URL,
This method will be called when I need to show the component

```
public show(): void {
    this.visible = true;
    this.visibleAnimate = true;
    console.log(this.src)
    this.DocURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.src);
    console.log(this.DocURL);
}


constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.visible = false;
    this.visibleAnimate = false;

    this.DocURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.location.host + "/pdf.pdf");
}
```

Heres the HTML Part

```
<div style=" height:650;width:870">
    <object width="870" height="650" type="application/pdf" [data]="DocURL" id="doc" #doc>
        <p>Not able to display the document</p>
    </object>
    <div style="display:none">
        <iframe id="fred" #fred style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="PDF in an i-Frame" [src]="DocURL" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="1100" width="850" ></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

The URL I am supplying will be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL does not have a protocol. Try the following:

```
this.DocURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + "/pdf.pdf");
```

Comment: what to do if i have pdf like https   + : +  //  abc.com/mytest.pdf ?   (+ is for giving hint bez posting is not allowed )