# angular 7 image display using filepath from api

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to display an image in Angular 7 from an API.
I can retrieve the image either as form-data or by path of the image.
So how do I display it in Angular?

I already tried to display an image using its file path but had no success. The code I tried is given below.

TS FILE

```
this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}`,this.httpOptions)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.image=data['filePath'];
    this.finalImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.image);
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

HTML

```
<div> <img src="{{finalImage}}"> </div>
<div> <img [src]="finalImage"> </div>
<div> <img bind-src="finalImage"> </div>
```

Comment: what error you are seeing in console?

Comment: So what's the problem when you get image url from api and use `<img [src]="finalImage">`?

Comment: when I console this.finalImage the response is "changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: "C:/Users/SERVER/Desktop/Storage/upload/13-08-2019/18_Screenshot (5).png""

Comment: <img [src]="finalImage"> no image is displayed, like those icon of broken image is shown

Comment: Also there displays a warning: "WARNING: sanitizing unsafe URL value SafeValue must use [property]=binding: C:/Users/SERVER/Desktop/Storage/upload/13-08-2019/18_Screenshot (5).png (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)"

Comment: have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995986/changingthisbreaksapplicationsecurity-angular2